# To add gap between the ExpansionPanels in my ExpansionPanelList Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to add gap between my expansionPanels instead of the divider.
I dont wish to change my approach ie use ExpansionTile etc
can anyone help me

i have been trying to add some gap between my ExpansionPanels

Here is my Code:

```dart
Container(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
          // padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
          child: ExpansionPanelList(
        expansionCallback:
            (int index, bool isExpanded) {
          toggleExpansion(index);
        },
        expandIconColor: Colors.white60,
        animationDuration:
            Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        dividerColor:
            Color.fromRGBO(44, 52, 83, 0.669),
        elevation: 1,
        expandedHeaderPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        children: devices
            .map<ExpansionPanel>((Device device) {
          return ExpansionPanel(
              backgroundColor:
                  Color.fromARGB(106, 44, 52, 83),
              headerBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                  bool isExpanded) {
                return Container(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          device.name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit,
                              color: Colors.white),
                          onPressed: () {
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext
                                  context) {
                                TextEditingController
                                    controller =
                                    TextEditingController(
                                        text: device
                                            .name);

                                return Dialog(
                                  shape:
                                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius
                                            .circular(
                                                16.0),
                                  ),
                                  elevation: 16.0,
                                  child: Container(
                                    decoration:
                                        BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius
                                              .circular(
                                                  16.0),
                                      gradient:
                                          LinearGradient(
                                        begin: Alignment
                                            .topCenter,
                                        end: Alignment
                                            .bottomCenter,
                                        colors: [
                                          Colors
                                              .purple,
                                          Colors
                                              .deepPurpleAccent
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          const EdgeInsets
                                              .all(
                                              16.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisSize:
                                            MainAxisSize
                                                .min,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            'Edit Device Name',
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(
                                              color:
                                                  Colors.white,
                                              fontSize:
                                                  18.0,
                                              fontWeight:
                                                  FontWeight.bold,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                              height:
                                                  12.0),
                                          TextField(
                                            controller:
                                                controller,
                                            decoration:
                                                InputDecoration(
                                              labelText:
                                                  'Device Name',
                                              labelStyle:
                                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                              height:
                                                  12.0),
                                          Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                            children: [
                                              TextButton(
                                                onPressed:
                                                    () {
                                                  Navigator.pop(context); // Close the dialog
                                                },
                                                child:
                                                    Text(
                                                  'Cancel',
                                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              TextButton(
                                                onPressed:
                                                    () {
                                                  // Update the device name in the list
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    device.name = controller.text;
                                                  });

                                                  // Close the keyboard
                                                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

                                                  Navigator.pop(context); // Close the dialog
                                                },
                                                child:
                                                    Text(
                                                  'Save',
                                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        device.isExpanded =
                            !isExpanded;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              body: Container(
                color:
                    Color.fromARGB(64, 44, 52, 83),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    device.lastOnline,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    device.ipAddress,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  trailing: Icon(
                    Icons.delete,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(
                        199, 255, 43, 50),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      devices.removeWhere(
                          (Device currentdevice) =>
                              device ==
                              currentdevice);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              isExpanded:
                  device.isExpanded ?? false);
        }).toList(),
        // [
        //   // Device1
        //   for (Device device in devices)
        //     buildExpansionPanel(device, toggleExpansion),
        // ],
      )),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: please share your code what you have done in it.

Comment: i have added my code now
I wish to find a solution with using Expansion Panel